# Which Outlier Detection Method? Why?

Tags: statistics, anomaly-detection, outlier

For detecting an outlier in a vector I have tested different well known outlier detection methods. Finally, I used combination of different methods and an agreement between those methods. Now, a person asks why did you choose this combination and algorithms!? You can reach different combinations and use other algorithms and they may yield better results. What should I answer? I cannot just say based on tests as there are many other algorithms that I haven't tested (cannot test all algorithms). It is not a logical response, I think.

I'm looking for tests to justify my selected methods and combination and say why I have selected these methods.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: If you use a few different standard methods, cite a good textbook that proposes such methods, and the list of outliers detected is fairly consistent and robust across these few methods, then you have some basis for your claim.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your model and what you're doing.

Comment: On what basis do you think that a statistical outlier is also one that is illegally manipulated?

Comment: Based on the context that I work

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: There is no hard definition of what should be considered an outlier. You can evaluate/label the detected outliers (review manually) for your specific application and use accuracy on the labeled set as a proxy for detection performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can justify your choices by using data.

Treat the anomaly detection like a supervised learning problem where the concept is being anomaly.
Then you'll be able to present - for each method - its confusion matrix.
Not only it will be a good justification, it will enable to understand the expected results.

Many times, we have models and we wonder which confidence threshold we should use for alerting. In the supervised learning framework you'll be able to do trade-off like "increasing the confidence to X will lead to a better precision Y yet a decrease of the recall to Z".

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have presented the result and it is acceptable. But the problem is that we cannot test all methods and their combinations as there are plenty of algorithms. Suppose one says you may get better result if replace grubb method with IQR or many other algorithms which lead to different combinations. Now I should say my reasons for my selections and then mention that there is no need to test other methods as our results are acceptable. I'm wondering that is there any solution by inspecting data distribution and relating it to functionality of used methods?

Comment: It is very common to have more ideas and methods than time to evaluate them. If we continue in the supervised framework, you can turn each method into a feature.  Then you can use feature selection to find the methods that works best for you case. You'll be able to omit methods that aren't useful or contribute nothing more than a different method that you already use. After that you will be able to build a model upon these feature  in order to find a way to aggregate them. This direction isn't the optimal but it is a common useful tradeoff.

Comment: Thank you. How can we turn a method to a feature? Am I right by the following  description: We calculate the standard deviation (SD) of the vector and add it as a new feature. Calculate median and add it as a new feature and etc. Then we use feature selection (say CFS method) and if for example SD of the vector remains (is highly correlated with target value) we say SD method  is better than median method in this context? Please explain more.

Comment: You can use the internal parameters of the method as features but it is not required. It is enough to use the predication itself of the method - whether it is considered an anomaly. Let's say that you use the 3 sigma rule(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). There is no need the store the mean and standard deviation as features. Just store whether the value is at least 3 SDs above the mean.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Great. What about algorithms like k-means or FCM? How can turn it to a feature like the one you mentioned for 3 sigma?

Comment: I don't see this answers the question.

Comment: Yes. it is not ideal solution but is justifiable. I mean it is better than relying just doing experiments blindly. I think the ideal solution ( to why these algorithms are used) should include  data distribution analysis and the mathematical approach of the method and their relation.

Comment: In general, you can treat the prediction each method that give you predictions. How do you use k-means for outlier detection? Are the outliers the samples too far from all k-means?

Comment: Yes. outliers are the samples which are far from all k-means and highly densed clusters.

Comment: OK. So it is possible to use this logic for prediction and turn the prediction into binary feature if "is too far from k-means centers", no?

Comment: Maybe possible but I think finding a good integral parameter for these kind of algorithms will be better? Do you have any suggestion to find a good integral parameter for such algorithms which are good representation of the whole method?

Comment: Oh, that is a different question from the reduction. I'm not sure that I understand the new question fully. Are you looking for the parameter (e,g,m the distance in k-means) that will be optimal as a threshold for classifying a sample as a outlier?

Comment: No. I mean converting K-means to a feature. More specifically, a measure which is a good representation of it like the one we said about  standard deviation method.Then, we can add that feature to dataset and use feature selection to inspect the correlation and it suitability as you mentioned by yourself.

Comment: It seems that taking the minimal distance of a sample to the k centers will be a good way to represent that feature.

Answer (score 3):

I would add to Dan Levin's answer that when you want to justify a method, the "scientific/engineering way" is to first produce a **bibliographical study**, where you basically prove that your approach covers an important part of what is commonly known as state-of-the-art methods. I would resume this as follow:

1. Look for commonly used methods that are known to be efficient for outlier detection.
2. Summarize their applicability domains (medicine, biology, network security..) and try to link their strong points to your application in order to select some promising methods.
3. Try the selected methods with usual validation processes inherent to machine learning problems.

**Defining what the state-of-the-art** consists of a **lot of work**, is absolutely **necessary** and is very **specific to your application**.